# TeamCity C# compile error: Invalid expression term 'int'

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, visual-studio-2017

A project that compiles locally (targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1) fails on TeamCity with the following message:

> [CoreCompile] Csc [Csc] Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
>
> [19:02:15][Csc]
>   Services\MyFile.cs(20, 55): error CS1525: Invalid expression term
>   'int'
>
> [19:02:15][Csc] Services\MyFile.cs(20, 59): error CS1003: Syntax
>   error, ',' expected

I also get a lot of these in the failed compile in red writing:

> [Step 5/9] The target "MvcBuildViews" listed in a BeforeTargets
>   attribute at "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
>   (845,131)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firstly, if it might help anybody, when TeamCity fails a step, a lot of text in that step will be red in color (even mere warnings), so at first I ran into a dead-end with believing the second error message was the problem. It wasn't.

Turns out, my Resharper 2016.3.2 (on Visual Studio 2017) had changed the following

```cs
int newInt;
if (!int.TryParse(theChar.ToString(), out newInt))
    return false;
```

into

```cs
if (!int.TryParse(theChar.ToString(), out int newInt))
    return false;
```

via an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> refactoring called ***"Inline variable declaration"*** (which normally sounds pretty harmless) and I was like, well, ok then.

This was not causing any trouble locally, since it's a c# 7 syntax thing, but on my TeamCity build-agent the compiler would fail because of too low version of MSBuild.

Comment: You probably know this already, but if you want to use the latest language features on TeamCity, you need to install the latest version of the Build-Tools (from Chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/packages/microsoft-build-tools/15.0.26228.0) or https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017.

Comment: @BoyanKostadinov Thanks, dude. Yeah, for sure, for the time being I just un-refactored it. I was also pretty crazed out about that I hadn't seen that notation before. Turns out, I really hadn't :D

Comment: I had this, but it compiled in Visual Studio, but TeamCity was using MSBuild. Strange how one allows it but the other doesn't!

Comment: you can also add a reference to Microsoft.Net.Compilers from version 2.0.1 onwards, and it will solve the problem in teamcity.